# Problems committing deleted directory to SVN repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I'm using Eclipse Europa with Subversive SVN plugin.

When try to commit deleted directory SVN returns this message:

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
Item is out of date
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Item '/myProject/trunk/src/test/config' is out of date
```

Content of the folder has been already deleted and committed.

What can I do to commit it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try updating first, *then* delete and commit.

Comment: For some reason, svn will bitch about this even if you are on HEAD.

Answer (score 10):

Had this issue too. What solved it for me was the following

- Update
- Delete contents of folder
- Commit
- Update
- Delete folder
- Commit

Frustrating to have to do this in 2 stages!

Answer (score 4):

Just delete the folder using *Svn repository exploring*, then update the project.

Answer (score 2):

Just right click on the Update to Head and then commit its works for me

Answer (score 2):

I could see that this ticket is old but the below steps might help someone who is facing the issue.

```
1. Update the parent folder.
2. Delete the folder you want to delete from the working repository.
3. Commit the parent folder.
```

I use Subclipse plugin in eclipse which has very user-friendly GUI to support Subversion. May be try if interested - https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too, but I had already deleted the folder.  Neither update nor commit would work, so I had to manually recreate the folder with the files in it, then follow the steps Kurru suggested.